# Crop Video temporary

Tags: video-editor, time-lapse, video-capture

I am in need of **Video Player**, or **Software** or **API** or any other idea for that help me to save the storage issue. 
Let me explain, I have a video file about `300mb` which contains 10 clips if i make video in parts each part is of size arround `20mb` so in total i will have `11 files` and `500mb` and it sucks because i have video files in thousands, So is their any video player or software by which i can crop/split video online so it don't affect my server space.

In best of knowledge the better way is I have to take a video and just take particular part from the video during run-time by telling its frame/time range and play it. So in this case i will not get headache of file-system again and storage issue also.

Can anyone suggest me something or any better idea please?

Comment: What format are your clips to begin with? You don't say what you're output is? What software are you using an editor or a utility.. What OS are you using?

Comment: @integris if you read first sentence "I need a software". And i am using windows OS. Please read description again i hope you will understand my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) might do what you need. It's pretty powerful commandline tool to convert video formats, sizes, etc.

Here is a clear and simple tutorial for installing [FFMpeg and using basic functions](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ffmpeg-guide/)

Here is a specific SuperUser thread about using it to cut [small clips from a larger clip](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video).

> So is their any video player or software by which i can crop/split
>   video online so it don't affect my server space.

There are a couple of "online editors" [such as WeView](https://www.wevideo.com/academy), I haven't used them.

FFMpeg can read files from a stream or ftp, see the documentation: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#ftp

But if I understand you correctly, you want the software to cut the clips and convert them totally on server. I do not think that is possible with normal protcols. FFMpeg may be able to download and cut the file in one script. But I suggest posing that as a separate question if you decide to use it.